# Jquery in Child Theme

Tags: themes, jquery, javascript, child-theme, tooltip

I am new to Wordpress and I need help with integrating my own jquery into a child theme.

I have this jquery tooltip which works but I want to include it into my wordpress child theme.

Have a look at the source code for this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.balloon.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sample').balloon({ position: "left" })  
    });
    </script>
```

How do I put all these in the child theme for the tooltip to work?
Thanks

Comment: you can add the scripts with the function `wp_enqueue_script` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, jquery is most likely already enqueued by the main theme. But if not, the proper way is to call `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` in a function for the action hook wp_enqueue_scripts.

Example:

```
function enqueue_jquery() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery').
```

This code would need to be added to the **`functions.php`** file for your child theme.

You would only specify a file name in `wp_enqueue_script` if you wanted to load a jquery version different than the one that comes with wordpress, or the one that comes with your main theme. And you would then need to make sure that any version of jquery already loaded is unloaded first, with `wp_deregister_script('jquery')`. Not deregistering an already loaded jquery version before loading a new one will lead to conflicts (same jquery functions defined twice...).

Then, for your **`jquery.balloon.js`** file, same remark, use `wp_enqueue_script` (and action `hook wp_enqueue_scripts`). You should also avoid using relative url's. Assuming you put the **`jquery.balloon.js`** file under the "js" directory for your child-theme, standard in WordPress would be to use code along the lines of:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-balloon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.balloon.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
```

The `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` function will return the full path url to your child-theme directory.

**EDIT** (had forgotten to include the activation of the balloon effect)

For the activation part (the `$(document).ready(...);` code), the most standard WordPress way to do things (and the one that will have the least disruption potential in terms of main - child theme relationship) is to create a js file with it, called for instance "**`balloonactivate.js`**", and put that file in the "js" folder for your child-theme.

Let's say that your child theme is for a theme called "maintheme"; then your child-theme should be in a folder called "maintheme-child" (ie, `wp-content/themes/maintheme-child`). In the "js" folder below (which either already exists, or which you will have created to put the "jquey.balloon.js" file), put the "**`strong text`**balloonactivate.js" file. The only thing left to do is to enqueue it like the jquery and jquery.balloon.js scripts.

So, the complete code that could work for you is as follows:

```
function enqueue_jquery_balloon() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-balloon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.balloon.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
   wp_enqueue_script('activate-balloon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/balloonactivate.js', array('jquery-balloon'), false, false);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery_balloon').
```

This code should be added to the **`functions.php`** file in the directory for your child-theme.

For the activation of the balloon effect, the `$(document).ready(...);` code could also be added inline at the end of the child-theme footer.php file (if the child-theme requires a footer that is different from the main theme one). But if the main theme footer suffices, it would be a pity to create a **`footer.php`** in the child-theme just for the balloon script (hence the comment above about the "least disruptive" impact of the **`balloonactivate.js`** file).

Enqueuing jquery is probably not needed in your case, but enqueuing it again is not an issue. What would be an issue is if one version of jquery was already loaded, and that you loaded a second one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please @Phil R., what about: `<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sample').balloon({ position: "left" })  
    });
    </script>` Where do I place it?

Comment: @Finerwhite, oops, forgot about that part. Will edit the answer to include it.

Comment: thank you very much. It had worked! But now, my drop-down menu is not working since I deregister the theme's jquery and enqueued the an external jquery that works with the balloon effect

Comment: Do you need to deregister the jquery version that your main theme enqueues? What version of jquery does balloon need and what version does your main theme need?

Comment: The balloon does not work when I dont deregister the wordpress version. The wordpress version is 1.11.4 and the balloon version is 4.2.4

Comment: Something isn't quite right, here. The latest jquery.balloon.js version is 0.5.0. The 4.2.4 version that you are referring to is the WordPress software version, which is added by default to scripts when no version is specified for the script. From what I could see, jquery.balloon.js will work with any jQuery version >= 1.7.0. The jQuery version that is loaded from WP is 1.11.4. Please try without de-registering the jQuery loaded by WP, and without enqueuing jQuery in the code (remove the `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` in the function).